# finding infimum

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> find the infimum and supremum of $E=\{x \in \mathbb{R}:x=\frac{2}{n}+(-1)^n, n\in \mathbb{N}\} $

$Max(E)=2$ therefore it is also the $Sup(E)$

Let assume that there is $-1<m: m\in E$ so $-1$ is not the infimum of $E$, so there is $m=\frac{2}{n}-1<-1\rightarrow \frac{2}{n}<0$ and because $n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that can not be, so $inf(E)=-1$

Is the prove is valid?

Comment: $\inf A =-1 , \sup A =2$

Comment: For the supremum, I would add a short proof that 2 really is the maximum. For the second part, you show that there is no $m<-1$ in $E$ and therefore the infimum is *at least* $-1$. You still need to show that it is no greater than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the infimum is $-1$ you have to show two things:

1. That $-1$ bounds $E$ from below;
2. That it's the greatest lower bound.

For the first part, if $n$ is odd then we have to show that $-1 \leq 2/n - 1$ but this is true since $2/n \geq 0$ for any $n.$ If $n$ is even then it's even easier since $-1 \leq 0 \leq 2/n + 1.$ In any case we have shown that $-1 \leq 2/n + (-1)^n$ for any $n.$

Now for the second part suppose $m$ is another lower bound and $-1 < m.$ Then all we have to do is find a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $2/n + (-1)^n < m,$ which will contradict the assumption that $m$ is a lower bound. Clearly we should pick an odd $n$ to make our life easier; thus our goal is to find an odd $n$ that satisfies $2/n - 1 < m.$ If we express $n$ in terms of $m$ we find $n > 2/(m+1),$ where crucially we used the fact that $m+1 > 0.$ So any such odd $n$ will do.

Comment: So we assume that $m$ is the infimum and then that it does not fulfill the requirements? should we try to prove that it does answer the requirements and get a contradiction?

Comment: @gbox It's a proof by contradiction. We want to show that $-1$ is the greatest lower bound, i.e., that for any lower bound $m$ we have $m \leq -1.$ So to argue by contradiction we suppose that there *exists* a lower bound $m$ such that $m > -1,$ the opposite condition, and then we arrive at a contradiction.